# boost asio example compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, httpserver

i am very very beginner in boost and trying to compile c++ program from this link:
 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3 
(httpserver3 example)
and so i tried to compile this project by using this command(in linux [debian]):

**g++ -o htserv.exe connection.cpp main.cpp mime_types.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp server.cpp**

or

**g++ -Wall -g -I /usr/local/include/boost connection.cpp main.cpp mime_types.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp server.cpp -o htserv**

and  then i see this error :

```
In file included from connection.cpp:11:0:
connection.hpp:20:23: fatal error: request.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from server.hpp:19:0,
                 from main.cpp:16:
connection.hpp:20:23: fatal error: request.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
request_handler.cpp:18:23: fatal error: request.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
request_parser.cpp:12:23: fatal error: request.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from server.hpp:19:0,
                 from server.cpp:11:
connection.hpp:20:23: fatal error: request.hpp: No such file or directory
```

yes you right i checked the permission and i have a new problem when i compile and a was so confused

```
/tmp/ccj4xp5E.o: In function `http::server3::connection::handle_read(boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long)':
/home/avakh/Desktop/boost/httpserver3/connection.cpp:56: undefined reference to `http::server3::reply::to_buffers()'
/home/avakh/Desktop/boost/httpserver3/connection.cpp:60: undefined reference to `http::server3::reply::stock_reply(http::server3::reply::status_type)'
/home/avakh/Desktop/boost/httpserver3/connection.cpp:64: undefined reference to `http::server3::reply::to_buffers()'
/tmp/ccj4xp5E.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccj4xp5E.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccj4xp5E.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccH8QGhE.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cclaofcI.o: In function `http::server3::request_handler::handle_request(http::server3::request const&, http::server3::reply&)':
/home/avakh/Desktop/boost/httpserver3/request_handler.cpp:34: undefined reference to `http::server3::reply::stock_reply(http::server3::reply::status_type)'
/home/avakh/Desktop/boost/httpserver3/request_handler.cpp:42: undefined reference to `http::server3::reply::stock_reply(http::server3::reply::status_type)'
/home/avakh/Desktop/boost/httpserver3/request_handler.cpp:66: undefined reference to `http::server3::reply::stock_reply(http::server3::reply::status_type)'
/tmp/cclaofcI.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_signal_blocker::posix_signal_blocker()':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_signal_blocker.hpp:43: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_signal_blocker::~posix_signal_blocker()':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_signal_blocker.hpp:50: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::~posix_thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_thread.ipp:35: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::join()':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_thread.ipp:42: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::start_thread(boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::func_base*)':
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_thread.ipp:50: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp:51: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:144: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:180: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::thread::~thread()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:255: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::thread::get_id() const':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:730: undefined reference to `boost::thread::native_handle()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::thread::join()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:756: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned long, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned long, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service*> > > >::~thread_data()':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:91: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
/tmp/ccJ7jCu1.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tImNS_4_mfi3mf0ImNS_4asio10io_serviceEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIPS7_EEEEEEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tImNS_4_mfi3mf0ImNS_4asio10io_serviceEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIPS7_EEEEEEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

then i tried to use this command for compile:
**gcc -I /usr/local/include/boost/ -lboost_thread -lboost-asio -lboost_noncopyable -lboost_bind -lboost_logic -lboost_tuple -lboost_array  connection.cpp mime_types.cpp main.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp server.cpp -o hserv**
and i had this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost-asio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_noncopyable
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_bind
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_logic
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_tuple
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_array
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

then i tried to use this command 
**g++ -I /usr/local/include/boost/ connection.cpp mime_types.cpp main.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp server.cpp -o hserv -lboost-asio -lboost_noncopyable -lboost_bind -lboost_logic -lboost_tuple -lboost_array**

and this had th error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost-asio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_noncopyable
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_bind
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_logic
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_tuple
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_array
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Show your compilation command.

Comment: BTW, Linux executable files often don't end with `.exe` conventionally....

Comment: Did you install a `libboost-all-dev` package under your Ubuntu or Debian system....

Comment: So, where is your request.hpp file? If you put it in the same directory as `connection.cpp` the example should work.

Comment: i installed libboost-all-dev package under debian and i put  request.hpp in the same directory as connection.cpp

Comment: And in which directory did you run `g++` ? Did you do a `pwd` and `ls` to check it?

Comment: yes i checked it and i was in true directory

Comment: You got something wrong. If the compiler tells `request.hpp: No such file or directory` you should believe it. Do the `ls -l request.hpp` command in the same terminal you are running your `g++` command.

Comment: You have to find out why and you need to learn more and understand more about Linux and compilation.

Comment: The order of your program arguments to `g++` is wrong, and that order is important. See my edited answer.

Comment: i used your advice and i had error yet i edit my question pleas look at this

Comment: I believe you should first learn a bit more about how to use `g++` and `make`. Try first with a pet project (not using any Boost thing). Your issues are not related to Boost, but to a general misunderstanding of how compiling and building programs should be done on Linux command line. Look also into existing free software (their source code, their `Makefile`, etc...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compilation command probably should start with `g++ -Wall -g -I/usr/include/boost`

<sup>where `-Wall` asks for all warnings, `-g` asks for debugging information, and `-I/usr/include/boost` adds an include directory to the include path.</sup>

And you really should use a builder like [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). It is time to learn how to write a `Makefile`. Then you should add in your `Makefile` a line like

```
  CXXFLAGS= -Wall -g -I/usr/include/boost
```

If `request.hpp` is your own file in the current directory (not one from some system library), you should include it with double-quotes characters like

```
  #include "request.hpp"
```

and not use `<request.hpp>` or else add `-I.` to your compilation command.

Be sure with the `pwd` and `ls` commands that you are running the compilation in the right directory. The `ls` command should show you both `request.hpp` and `connection.cpp`. Use the [cd](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucd.htm) command (which calls the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall) if needed. Take time to read more about [bash scripting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

You may want to pass `-v` (which shows the real programs launched for compilations) and `-H` (which shows the included files) to your compiler.

Remember that order of arguments to the `g++` compiler is important; source files should go before object files and libraries, and all should go from high-level to low-level (e.g. system libraries). Read the chapter about [invoking GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). You might need some `-L` options.

BTW, there are several HTTP server libraries available, e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (which supports both HTTP and HTTPS).

Comment: `request.hpp` is not a boost file, it is one of the files in the example.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Do you happen to know if libonion supports HTTPS? I need to query my program's configs via HTTPS from say a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in compiling with Ogre. I copied all the boost file(.a and .so) under /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib, it works.