# Compiling boost::asio example on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I am trying to switch to Windows environment from Linux, but find it a very hard path.

This time I wanted to test if I can work with boost library.

I had problems with compiling boost on windows, so I downloaded precompiled version. I unpacked everything and tested positively that I can compile the header-only librariers.

Then I copied some simple boost::asio example. I set up everything in Eclipse. Compilation went fine, but during linking I got 'undefined reference' problem to 'boost::system' internal stuff.

```
C:/Users/jacek/cpp/boost_1_62_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/jacek/cpp/boost_1_62_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
C:/Users/jacek/cpp/boost_1_62_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

So I added '-lboost_system', as well as the path to the libraries directory, to my linking options. But this did not help.

```
g++ "-LC:\\Users\\jacek\\cpp\\boost_1_62_0\\lib64-msvc-14.0" -o TestAsio.exe "src\\Main.o" -lboost_system
```

I checked the libraries directory and found there is a bunch of files containing 'boost_system' in the name. They are:

- libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_62.lib
- libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
- libboost_system-vc140-mt-s-1_62.lib
- libboost_system-vc140-mt-sgd-1_62.lib
- libboost_system-vc140-s-1_62.lib
- libboost_system-vc140-sgd-1_62.lib

I did not know which I should use. I tried adding 'libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_62' to the linking options, I tried all other files, I tried renaming the files to the linux pattern 'libboost_system.a', but nothing worked.

```
g++ "-LC:\\Users\\jacek\\cpp\\boost_1_62_0\\lib64-msvc-14.0" -o TestAsio.exe "src\\Main.o" -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-1_62 -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_62 -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-s-1_62 -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-sgd-1_62 -llibboost_system-vc140-s-1_62 -llibboost_system-vc140-sgd-1_62
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Please help...
YotKay

Comment: "-LC:\\ looks strange, -L "C:\\ ?

Comment: I think I found myself a solution here: http://boost.org/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: The point is that the precompiled binaries were compiled with Visual Studio and they are NOT COMPATIBLE with G++. Shit!

Comment: Binaries are also not compatible with any other version of Visual Studio than the one the compiled them. That is why there are released binaries for several different compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself with the help of a comment from this post: [boost asio example compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692053/boost-asio-example-compilation-error?rq=1)

It looks like the precompiled version of Boost is created with Visual Studion and is NOT COMPATIBLE with G++. I if I decided to install MinGW then I cannot use the precompiled version of boost, but must compile it myself using g++.

I did that. 
Now I have libraries compiled with G++.

I specify the path to the boost system library like that:
    c:\Users\jacek\cpp\boost_1_62_0\libraries\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-6.2.0\debug\link-static\

and add this option:
-lboost_system-mgw62-d-1_62

Now the problem with boost::system disappears. However, another one pops up with boost asio, but luckily the answer is here: [MinGW linker error: winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033608/mingw-linker-error-winsock)

The example works fine now on my Windows 10 laptop.

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;

int main()
{
  io_service ioservice;

  steady_timer timer{ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{3}};
  timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    { std::cout << "3 sec\n"; });

  ioservice.run();
}
```